# i want to convert Edit Text value to integer

Tags: android

I want to convert the value of an `EditText` and then increase this value with each click, but it is not working. Please help.

```
public void getMe(View v) {

    display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtv);
    enterno=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    String num1=enterno.getText().toString();
    num1.setText(Integer.toString(num1));  
    num1++;
    display.setText(""+num1);
}
```

Comment: num1 is a String variable, you can not use setText() method with it. setText() can be used with TextView and EditText.

Comment: Look at this line again: `num1.setText(Integer.toString(num1));` What is that supposed to do?

Comment: You should probably clear your `Java` concepts before moving to `Android` development.

Answer (score 1):

```
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtv);
enterno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
intValue = Integer.valueOf(enterno.getText().toString());
intValue++;
display.setText(String.valueOf(intValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

update your code:

```
public void getMe(View v){

         display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtv);
            enterno=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

         String num1 = enterno.getText().toString();
          int no = Integer.parseInt(num1);     
           no++;
            display.setText(String.valueOf(no));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer in one line:

`display.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(enterno.getText().toString()) + 1));`

just copy paste above line